# Arrows in NumberLinePlot

Tags: plotting

This question is about `NumberLinePlot` over a series of *closed* intervals. I want there to be arrowheads at the ends of each of these intervals. Is there any way to do this? I've tried

```
NumberLinePlot[{Interval[{0, 0.1}], 
                Interval[{0.2, 0.3}]}, 
                {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.1, 0.3}], 
 Spacings -> None]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NumberLinePlot[{Interval[{0, 0.1}], Interval[{0.2, 0.3}]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[{-0.03, 0.03}], Spacings -> None, ImageSize -> 700] /.
 {Line -> Arrow, Point[__] :> Nothing}
```

[image]